# Firebase Cloud Message service api call show message in logs but not in pop up

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use FCM API call to send Push notification for a specific topic. It works well via firebase console but when I use API call I can see a message in logs but pop does not appear.

Comment: What is the request that you are sending to the API?